# Fixar Elementos na DIV

Tags: html, css

Estou montando uma página HTML com algumas divs, e dentro de uma delas existe um `input` e um `button`. Porém quando faço zoom out, as divs ficar alinhadas do jeito certo, mas o botão e o `input` saem da div.
Como faço para que o botão e o `input` acompanhem a div e não saltem para fora?

```
<div id="search">
            <form action="../php/CONSULTA.php" id="consulta" name="consulta" onsubmit="return validateFormC()" method="GET">
                    <b>Código para Consulta:</b>
                    <input type="text" name="CODIGOC" MAXLENGTH="13" size="11" value="" onkeypress="return Only_N(event)" />
                    <button type="submit" id="consulta" class="btnCons">CONSULTAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#search{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:67%;
    border:solid black 1px;
    width:356px;
    height:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que basta você definir larguras para os elementos dentro de `#search` com `%`.
Você tem que colocar o código dentro de um script CSS, mas o melhor é colocar em um arquivo separado.
Um exemplo:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #search input {width:20%;}
    .btnCons {width:20%;}
</style>
```

E o que tem atrapalhado é o `width` de `#search`. Tente colocando o `width` como `auto` ou aumentar a largura. Além disso, o `margin-left` pode estar empurrando a div muito para a esquerda. Olha [este exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ws60qqev/).

Comment: Como faço para definir o tamanho de um botao e um input no CSS? Tentei definir <input type="text" name="CODIGOC" MAXLENGTH="13" size="11%" value="" onkeypress="return Only_N(event)" /> mas continuou a mesma coisa, quando realizo zoom out ele sai da div.

Comment: Andrey, mas isso não foi nem uma critica nem uma solicitação. Talvez não seja a resposta que ele esteja procurando, mas foi uma resposta

Comment: @Thiago uma outra coisa que pode estar atrapalhando é o `margin-left`, pode estar empurrando a div muito para a esquerda e alterando o comportamento http://jsfiddle.net/ws60qqev/

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso o width da div search não pode ser maior que 32%, uma vez que a div está 67% á esquerda (67%+32=99%). Retire também o tamanho do input. Defina a tamanho da letra da div search para font-size:16px (ou qualquer outro valor). Ponha o formulário a zeros:

```
form{
margin :0;
padding:0;
width:auto;
}
```

Teste no chrome ou no firefox e use as ferramentas de desenvolvedor dos browsers para ver o layout. Faça alterações e teste.

```
<input type="text" name="CODIGOC" MAXLENGTH="13" value="" onkeypress="return Only_N(event)" />
<button type="submit" id="consulta" class="btnCons">CONSULTAR</button>
```